# Yii2 Autocomplete Widget Categories

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, yii2, jquery-ui-autocomplete

JQuery's Autocomplete supports categories in the autocomplete results. Like in the link below (just type the letter 'a'):

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/categories.html

Yii2's jQuery Autocomplete widget has a `source` parameter that can take in an array for the results of the Autocomplete. But when I give it a multi-dimensional array, trying to get categories like the link above, it breaks the Autocomplete. See below:

```
AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'search_terms',
    'options' => [
        'style' => 'width:100%;',
    ],
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => ['NA' => ['USA', 'CAN'], 'EUR' => ['RUS', 'SPN']],
    ],
])
```

How do I get categories working in Yii2's Autocomplete widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of widgets is just a wrapper of Javascript plugin allowing you to register it using PHP code (configure properties using PHP arrays instead of Javascript objects, etc.). If you investigate the sources of [AutoComplete](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui/blob/master/AutoComplete.php) widget and parent classes, you will not find any special processing of `source` property. That means you need to follow jQuery UI plugin docs, click the "view source" link [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) to show code. JS part looks like this:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
      _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
      },
      _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
          currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
          var li;
          if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
            ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
            currentCategory = item.category;
          }
          li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
          if ( item.category ) {
            li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
          }
        });
      }
    });
    var data = [
      { label: "anders", category: "" },
      { label: "andreas", category: "" },
      { label: "antal", category: "" },
      { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
      { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
    ];

    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data
    });
  } );
</script>
```

As you can see, you are passing categories wrong. Try this instead:

```
'source' => [
    ['label' => 'USA', 'category' => 'NA'],
    ['label' => 'CAN', 'category' => 'NA'],
    ['label' => 'RUS', 'category' => 'EUR'],
    ['label' => 'RUS', 'category' => 'SPN'],
],
```

Also for this case maybe you need to include additional JS (above plugin registration) to completely reproduce example.